# How to sort custom coupon column in Woo Orders list?

Tags: woocommerce, coupon

I have added a custom column to the Woo orders page that displays any coupons used by the orders but I can't seem to make it sortable.  I have added the column successfully and can enable sorting on the column header, but I cannot figure out how to code the sort function.

It seems from [Sort coupon list column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71434519/add-sorting-to-code-column-in-woocommerce-coupon-list) that the coupon data is not stored in the order table meta so do I need some form of join in the query to the Coupon data in the Query?  If so, how is that done?

What I have so far:

Column setup

```
// Additional custom coupon column
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shop_order_coupon_column', 20 );
function custom_shop_order_coupon_column( $columns ) {
    $reordered_columns = array();
    foreach( $columns as $key => $column){
        $reordered_columns[$key] = $column;
        if( $key ==  'order_status' ){
            $reordered_columns['coupons'] = __( 'Coupons', 'woocommerce');
        }
    }
    return $reordered_columns;
}

// Custom column coupon content
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'custom_shop_order_column_coupons_content' );
function custom_shop_order_column_coupons_content( $column ) {
    global $post, $the_order;

    if ( ! is_a( $the_order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        $the_order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
    }
    
    if ( 'coupons' === $column ) {
        $coupon_codes = $the_order->get_coupon_codes();   
        if ( ! empty($coupon_codes) ) {
            echo implode(', ', $coupon_codes);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have added the code to make it sortable like this:

```
 // Make custom column sortable
function filter_manage_edit_shop_order_sortable_coupon_columns( $sortable_columns ) {  
    return wp_parse_args( array( 'coupons' => 'coupon_codes' ), $sortable_columns );
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_sortable_columns', 'filter_manage_edit_shop_order_sortable_coupon_columns', 10, 1 );

function action_pre_get_posts_for_coupons( $query ) {   
    // If it is not admin area, exit
    if ( ! is_admin() ) return;  
    global $pagenow, $post_type;

    // Compare
    if ( $query->is_admin && $pagenow === 'edit.php' && $post_type === 'shop_order' && $query->get( 'orderby' ) == 'coupon_codes' ) {
    
        // >>>>>>>>>>>> 
        // this won't work for coupons as not stored in order meta!!
         
        // Get orderby
        $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby' );

        // Set query
        if ( $orderby == 'coupon_amount' ) {           
            $query->set( 'meta_key', 'coupon' );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        }
        // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'action_pre_get_posts_for_coupons', 10, 1 );
```

Any pointers on how to order the Order list by coupon codes would be greatly appreciated.
-Colin